# Compile error when using modulus operator in MarkupTemplateEngine

Tags: groovy

I have been using the Groovy template engine without issue for about a year, but just ran into a strange issue and I'm not sure if I'm crazy, or this is expected behavior.

All things being equal, using this function throws a compile error when used inside a Groovy template.

```
def isEven(n) { n % 2 == 0 }
```

> General error during class generation: org.codehaus.groovy.ast.Parameter cannot be cast to org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.VariableExpression

But if I do it this way...

```
def isEven(n) { n.mod(2) == 0 }
```

...everything works as expected.

I didn't notice any special case in the docs, but I could have missed it. Could anyone offer some insight into the meaning behind this error, and perhaps offer some guidance to avoid pitfalls like this in the future?

Cheers, and thank you!

*Groovy version 2.5*

**Update**
Here is a full example template that throws the error.

```
def isEven(n) { n % 2 == 0 }
def items = ["Zero", "One", "Two"]
yieldUnescaped '<!DOCTYPE html>'
html(lang:'en') {
    body {
        ul {
            items.eachWithIndex { item, i ->
                if(isEven(i)) li(item)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is an example of how the template is rendered.

```
TemplateConfiguration config = new TemplateConfiguration();         
MarkupTemplateEngine engine = new MarkupTemplateEngine(config);     
Template template = engine.createTemplate(new File('test.tpl').newReader());    
Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();                        
Writable output = template.make(model);                             
output.writeTo(new File('test.html').newWriter());
```

Changing the isEven method to use Number.mod compiles just fine.

Comment: I can't tell what this has to do with `MarkupTemplateEngine` and I can't tell in what context that `isEven` method is being defined.  The code at https://gist.github.com/jeffbrown/a6863790bd84ce2363f5014f7df1df46 seems to work.  Can you provide some more context or some info to help reproduce the problem?

Comment: Which templating engine?  Do you have a short self-contained example that shows the error?

Comment: It has to do with MarkupTemplateEngine, in that is what I was using when I trigged the error. My underlying issue is that using the modulus operator anywhere in the template throws the error, while using the Number.mod method in Groovy SDK works as expected. The isEven just demonstrates the difference between working or not. The % symbol is clearly causing some kind of preprocessing error, but I'm not exactly sure what has there is no mention in MarkupTemplateEngine docs (although GStringTemplateEngine does use <% foo %> style processing, so maybe its related?

Comment: @tim_yates Example added in edits